# Store paperclip files only on s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

Is possible to store files only on s3?

I need paperclip only for download and metadata store because upload files directly to s3.

EDIT: I use already s3 storage but with this configuration paperclip prior to upload to s3 store on filesystem. Have resolved partially by [upload direct to s3](http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and) but paperclip on model create/update download file from s3, check content type and other default things so upload the same file.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Bharat, you can [upload directly to S3 using Paperclip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) like this:

```
  #config/environments/production.rb
  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!({
    storage: :s3,
    s3_host_name: 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    },
    bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
  })
```

This will set your "default" settings to upload the required files to S3

---

**Paperclip**

You have to remember that Paperclip doesn't actually "store" files -- it just handles the interaction between ActiveRecord & your storage facility

Most applications will store the files in their local file structure (`/public/system`), but by using the `s3:` storage setting, you'll be able to upload them directly to S3